# xcode: NSArray slice method?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, nsarray, nsset

How can I create a NSSet or NSArray X with first 5 elements of NSArray or NSSet Y?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
NSArray *X = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo", @"bar", @"test", @"blah", @"yeah", @"lost", nil];    
NSArray *Y = [X subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0,5)];
```

The resulting array Y will contain the first five elements of the first array X.

Comment: `NSRangeMake` should be `NSMakeRange`.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray x = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
[x addObject:[y objectAtIndex:i]];
}
```

(y is the other NSMutableArray)